# Qlik Sense - Create bar chart by summing multiple columns

Tags: boxplot, qlikview, qliksense

I have several columns of data that are numeric and I want Qlik to create a boxplot by Group which is the sum of each column:

```
Group   Data1   Data2   Data3   Data4   Data5   Data6
1       0       2       0       0       1       0
1       1       3       1       0.5     0       1
2       2       4       0       0       0       0
2       3       5       0       0       0       2
3       3       5       0       0       0       2
```

If Qlik took the sum of each column, it would look like this:
[image]

Obviously, you could chose which Groups to plot.  The problem is that I'm trying to plot multiple columns in a single boxplot and I can't find anything similar. I don't know where to begin with this, so any help would be appreciated.

--- update ---
The problem is that boxplots are generally created using a single column and then an aggregate function (sum, count, etc) is applied. So, a typical boxplot would use Group and then count the number of times each group occurs.  In my case, I need a single chart with the sum of each Data (Data1 - Data6) column plotted by group.  So, my problem is that the single boxplot is derived from several columns, not one.

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding you well. So you want to plot 3 boxes (1 per group) which contain the distribution of data (from data1 to data6)?. Note that I said "distribution", not "sum", because a boxplot is not used to show sums. I think you should take a look to this example: https://community.qlik.com/blogs/qlikviewdesignblog/2014/08/18/recipe-for-a-box-plot, or maybe edit your question so that it is more readable. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I will edit my question to clarify